# netbeans cannot find main class

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying my hands on a simple tutorials that

- connects a java program to a simple java DB
- using the NetBeans 7 IDE.

[Here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html) is the link to the tutorials.

But when I run the project, NetBeans gives me the following error:

```
 run:
Error: Could not find or load main class database_console.DBConnect
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Below is the code for the main class:

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
          String uName="faisal";
          String uPass="password";
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);        
        }
        catch ( SQLException err ) {
          System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Any one with a suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Did u try restarting netbeans, and doing a clean / full rebuild?

Comment: no may e will try that now and get back to you

Comment: What directory is DBConnect in?

Comment: Closed netbeans and launched it again but did not solve the problem. Had to close the project from the Netbeans project pane , close the netbeans IDE, then launched the netbeans IDE again and finally opened the project again to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had to close the project from the Netbeans project pane ,
 closed the netbeans IDE, then launched the netbeans IDE again 
and finally opened the project again to solve the problem.

Comment: Sometimes, you need to delete the "cache" also: C:\Users\User\.netbeans\7.1.2\var\cache (in vista)